# Unix - Directory not empty. Error -126: remote rmdir failed

Tags: unix, ftp

I have the following directories on the root of my server

- htdocs

  - [site contents]
- mike-eng

  - stage
- old2
- stats

I am trying to delete the "mike-eng" directory here.

Permissions on "mike-eng" and "stage" are 777. Neither directory is showing **any** files in my FTP client (Transmit), which shows hidden files in other directories. Also, the command line shows the directories as empty:

> ftp> cd mike-eng
>
> 250 CWD command successful
>
> ftp> ls
>
> 229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||29910|)
>
> 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list
>
> drwxrwxrwx   2 1191966  15000        4096 Jan 11 15:55 stage
>
> 226 Transfer complete
>
> ftp> cd stage
>
> 250 CWD command successful
>
> ftp> ls
>
> 229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||48904|)
>
> 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list
>
> 226 Transfer complete

When I try to delete the "mike-eng" directory using Transmit, I get the following error:

> stage: Directory not empty
>
> Error -126: remote rmdir failed

When I connect using Terminal and try to delete the "mike-eng" directory from the command line, I get:

> ftp> rm mike-eng
>
> 550 mike-eng: Directory not empty

If I navigate inside the "mike-eng" directory and try to delete the "stage" directory, I get:

> ftp> rm stage
>
> 550 stage: Directory not empty

How can I delete this directory and its sub-directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No explanation for the cause of this, but the only way I was able to delete the directory was using my host(Powweb)'s "file manager" in the control panel.

Comment: Same here. Uploaded file had some weird character in it, and FTP couldn't browse to it, rename it, etc. Host file manager worked.

Answer (score 3):

There's probably a hidden file in `mike-eng`. Try

```
ftp> cd mike-eng
ftp> mdelete .*
ftp> cd ..
ftp> rmdir mike-eng
```

Comment: ftp> cd mike-eng
250 CWD command successful
ftp> mdelete .*
ftp> cd ..
250 CWD command successful
ftp> ls
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||8848|)
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list
-rw-r--r--   1 1191966  15000    6819809280 Jan  6 16:43 backupfull.tar
drwxr-xr-x  17 1191966  15000        4096 Jan 10 22:15 htdocs
drwxrwxrwx   3 1191966  15020        4096 Jan 11 15:58 mike-eng
drwxr-xr-x  12 1191966  15000        4096 Jul  5  2009 old2
drwxr-xr-x   2 1191966  15000       24576 Jan 16 10:24 stats
226 Transfer complete
ftp> rmdir mike-eng
550 mike-eng: Directory not empty

Comment: @MikeEng: hmm, I guess the `mdelete` didn't catch everything. Can you try an `ls .*` in dir `mike-eng`?

Comment: `ftp> cd mike-eng
250 CWD command successful
ftp> ls .*
229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||46930|)
150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for file list
226 Transfer complete
ftp>`

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. It seems it's not the server, but a bug in Transmit.

Here's the solution that worked with me:

1. In Transmit's interface, open the directory that won't delete
2. Once opened, right click inside the directory and click: “Refresh”. Some files will show up!
3. Delete those files that came up and then now deleting the directory will work fine
4. Repeat that for all directories that present that error